# PyTesseract PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

At this point, my goal is to read a zip, open the PNGs in it, and convert them to strings using pytesseract. But I keep getting an error `No such file`, even when I know for a fact the exist. Here's my source code:

```
# load into memory PNGs from small_img.zip using ZipFile
with ZipFile(file_name, "r") as myzip:
    for name in myzip.namelist():
        with myzip.open(name, "r") as img:
            # search PNGs for keyword str "Christopher" using PyTesseract
            im = Image.open(img)
            print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

This is the output:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

By the way, I'm using PyCharm. And I have looked for solutions to that above error, and nothing I have tried has worked. I've redownloaded pytesseract, updated python, started a new venv, all to no avail. Python already has full security access, as does PyCharm. Some say a quick fix is to reformat the param, like so:

```
im = Image.open(fr'{img}')
```

And it gets past that error, but it gives me:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<zipfile.ZipExtFile name='a-0.png' mode='r' compress_type=deflate>"
```

Comment: Is the image open? Sometimes, it can cause these issues

Comment: This might work - `im = Image.open(img,mode='r')`. You can set modes for the file to get around the permission error

Comment: @PCM, When I try that I get the access error.

Comment: @Sujay, No, the image is not open.

Comment: Maybe you can try running python as an administrator. I am not sure it may work

Comment: There were several edits now. Could you please provide a [mre] to the last version of code you tested? The given code (right now) works properly for me.

Comment: @HansHirse, this is exactly what I'm running. Same error. I've only edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about this, but when you are trying to read the file by `im = Image.open(img.name)`, it is searching inside the base folder that is the folder where the python file is saved at, rather than searching in the zipfile. I am not sure what the solution is, but it might help. :)

Comment: (Writing this after you edited the question) Was the image file open in some other application. Permission denied error probably occurs due to this.

Comment: No, the file is not open in any other application.